# Office 365 Update Contacts

Tags: c#-4.0, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

i am using the REST API V1.0 to fetch and create contact,
i wanted to use update contact based on the ID in v1.0, what is the parameter needs to be passed for same.

to create new contact i am using https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts and to fetch contacts https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts?$select=EmailAddresses

Please let me know the same for update in V1.0

Comment: I tried with https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts/AAMkAGI2NGVhZTVlLTI1OGMtNDI4My1iZmE5LTA5OGJiZGEzMTc0YQBGAAAAAADUuTJK1K9aTpCdqXop_4NaBwCd9nJ-tVysQos2hTfspaWRAAAAAAEOAACd9nJ-tVysQos2hTfspaWRAAADTHkzAAA=   it is giving Error {"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisService","message":"Authentication for this service requires OAuth: outlook.office.com."}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update you need to `PATCH` to the URL of the contact (`/me/contacts/<contactId>`). The body would be a JSON payload with the properties to update.

Your OAuth error seems to indicate that you're not including your access token in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Sir, but i am using the Basic Authentication method

Comment: That explains it. You must use OAuth, Basic is not supported.